# launchd: Launch order for registered URL scheme

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

My app has a custom registered ULR scheme, lets call it `myapp://`. While developing there are multiple application versions on the system:

- A production version may be in `/Applications`
- The current build in `DerivedData`
- Archived versions for releases in `Archives`

Now when `myapp://` gets opened in e.g. the browser, it seems completely random as to which version is actually launched. One might guess it should be the last active or running version, but its not.

Can I somehow influence this launch order? How can I reliably test URL schemes with multiple versions on the system?

Comment: It may help that there is an “lsregister” command to query, add, or remove entries in the launch services database (compare https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/10523/30895).

Comment: I tried unregistering all entries using `lsregister` in a shell script, but to no avail. The entries immediately reappear.

Comment: Do your versions have different version *numbers*? As I recall, launch services will pick the version of an app with the highest version number (so long as it has been registered with the system, through `lsregister` or by being launched at least once).

Comment: The version number is only incremented if we release a build, so the dev version has the same version number as the current release.

Answer (score 0):

its ugly and brute force, but... can you "break" the apps that you don't want to launch?

e.g. a shell script like

break.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
mv /Applications/MyApp.app /Applications/MyApp.disable
mv /DerivedData/MyApp.app /DerivedData/MyApp.disable
for x in /Archives/*.app
  do mv /Archives/$x /Archives/$x.disabled
done
```

And then to restore do a script like restore.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash
 mv /Applications/MyApp.disable /Applications/MyApp.app
 mv /DerivedData/MyApp.disable /DerivedData/MyApp.app
 for x in /Archives/*.app
   do mv /Archives/$x Archives/`echo $x | sed -e /s/disabled//g`
 done
```

Obviously, edit the above to *not* break the one you want to keep working.

Comment: Might be a viable idea, however I would do it differently. Probably better to just `chmod -x` all matching apps. However a more robust approach than modifying attributes on every item in the filesystem would be preferable.

Comment: Yeah. I don’t have my Mac handy. Wasn’t sure if chmod would work without testing. Another option would be to zip the apps up and just leave the one you want to work available unzipped. Agreed it would be nice to have an answer about how to do it the “right” way. Just wanted to get out there that there are other ways that will work if you don’t mind being a little dirty.  Good luck!